# How do Jedi reassemble themselves?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

When a Jedi performs 'The Art of The Small' they reduce in size to that of an atom. How does a Jedi remember to reassemble themselves cell by cell if atoms have no consciousness or memory?

Comment: Erm, because this is dumb and no-one thought it through properly?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Art_of_the_Small

Comment: Consider that midichlorian is an organism that is supposed to exist with force users to let them use the force... and if they shrink themselves the midichlorians couldn't possibly be in them any more and thus they shouldn't have access to the force any more >.>

Comment: Because "luminous beings are we, not this  crude matter."

Comment: This is not 'dumb' as masters have reassembled themselves. I am merely just questioning the process.

Comment: @LordSalizar - Please don't take my comment as criticism of you. Your question is a perfectly sensible, well-written and cogent one.

Comment: Sure, but do they know 'The Art of the Possible' - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4HRVQKA7eY

Comment: @Lord Salizar - did you read that "art of the small" page on wookieepedia before posting your question? I just noticed that it actually contains the same quote I put in my answer, the one that specifically says "her physical body remains unchanged", so I wonder if your read it and just missed that line, or didn't see the page at all...if the latter, always do some basic googling before posting a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The Art of the Small article on wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Art_of_the_Small) it reduces their "presence in the force", not their actual body, so there should be no need to reassemble. This is elaborated in the "Healing" subsection of the "Force-Sensitive Abilities" section of the book [*Jedi vs. Sith: The Essential Guide to the Force*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_vs._Sith:_The_Essential_Guide_to_the_Force_(real-life_book)), which quotes a recording from a Jedi named [Cilghal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cilghal) about a conversation with a Force-user called [Vergere](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vergere) who used the technique of "making herself small":

> I met with Vergere in her cell, where she had spent many hours being debriefed by Fleet Intelligence. Although she appearead a bit tired, I found her to be entirely cooperative as she explained her healing technique to me. Essentially, she narrows her focus—**her mind and Force-awareness**—until it becomes microscopic. **While her physical body remains unchanged**, her projected form shrinks to an infinitesimal size. In that state, she can rearrange molecules, take them apart, and build new ones bit by bit.